# Trigger button click event based on shortcut key using hotkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, hotkeys

I am using hotkeys plugin for shortcut functionality, I want to trigger a button click when I press any shortcuts.

```
hotkeys.add({
combo: 'alt+1',
callback: function (data) {
     data.preventDefault();
   " click "TakeAwayButton" here to call functionality of directive"
}
});
```

When I click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> I want to trigger button click.

Button is :

```
<button type="button" id="TakeAwayButton" ng-click="orderType=1">Click Me </button>
```

Comment: Simply use .click() in your callback function it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `click()` function:

> Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or
>   trigger that event on an element.

```
hotkeys.add({
combo: 'alt+1',
callback: function (data) {
     data.preventDefault();
     $('#TakeAwayButton').click();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Library.Check this https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Comment: i have already gone through this library , didn't got solution there :(